# GDB: How to get the adress of a function declaration knowing the line number?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm discovering GDB and i would like to know if it's possible to get the memory address of the declaration of a function, for instance:

```
int func()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

How do I know at which address is declared the function `func()`?

Comment: You mean you want to know where exactly the stack for function `func()` begins? You want the starting address of it?

Comment: The starting address yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `info line <line number>` to get the address at line number as below:

```
(gdb) list
1   #include <stdio.h>
2   
3   int func()
4   {
5       return 1;
6   }
7   
8   int main()
9   {
10      func();
(gdb) info line 3
Line 3 of "test.c" is at address 0x4004ed <func> but contains no code.
(gdb) p &func
$1 = (int (*)()) 0x4004ed <func>
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declarations (and the type system) only matter to the compiler, they have no representation in the executable and thus no memory addresses (apart from debugging symbols).

`static`-linkage defintions, on the other hand, are laid out in memory by the linker and do have addresses. If you want to get the memory address of a symbol, you just need to use the `&` operator¹ on it:

```
(gdb) print &func
```

I am not sure, why exactly you need that though. In case you meant `func`'s stack frame, you can use `info frame` after selecting or stepping to the frame.

---

[1]: You can omit the `&` for functions.